# Undo the effect of .nomedia file for WhatsApp images

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, gallery, images

I downloaded ES File Manager and created a `.nomedia` file so that my WhatsApp images wouldn't automatically download into my gallery. But that sends ALL WhatsApp images to a hiding spot. Ideally, I want to select the images I want from WhatsApp and have those seen in my gallery. It seems there's no middle ground or way to do that. So, if I have to choose, I'd rather all media automatically go to my gallery and I'll delete the images I don't want. But I cannot figure out how to undo the "damage".

I finally located and "unhid" the `.nomedia` file, but I can't seem to send my pics back to the gallery or make them automatically go there.

Comment: Have you deleted the .nomedia file, then rebooted the device?

Comment: Clear the MediaStorage "app" in Android Settings and perform a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If all your WhatsApp images are located in the **same** directory, then I have to say that there doesn't exist a 'middle' solution. However, if those images lie in different directories (it's OK even if the directories are nested, i.e. one contains others), you can create `.nomedia` for them separately.

Please note that the 'effective range' of a `.nomedia` is the folder it is located in **and all the subfolders** under it. So if the directories are nested too complexly, the solution may not be very satisfactory.

To undo the effects of creating the `.nomedia` file you simply delete the same `.nomedia` file. Then force restart your gallery app or restart your phone.